# what is the best cross platform langwage to be used for on-air tv programs

Tags: animation, video, cross-platform, television

i am programming a software which is basically a game .
this software contain HD videos and animations .
 
we broadcast it on a TV channel On-Air .
what is the best cross platform language to be used to develop this software.
 
we did the same thing using flash professional CC, 
but we need more powerful tools that is especial for On-air TV show

Comment: i found that Ventus and Unity3d are candidates

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be hard to beat Flash in terms of ease-of-development and pure multimedia capabilities. I would strongly suggest sticking with Flash and outputting your video signal to an [HD capture card](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/decklink).